# HTML img tag not showing the image

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, asp.net-mvc-4

net mvc4 project.
I try to display Image with help of img tag, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>
            Select mail service:
        </h1>
        <img src="C:\Users\MvcContactsImporter\Graphics\YahooLogo.jpg"/>
    </div>
    @RenderBody()
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

But in FireFox browser I get this:

[image]

and if I change browser to Internet Explorer I get this:

[image]

The extention, name and the path of the files are correct.

Any idea what may cause to the problem and how to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: change this `C:\Users\MvcContactsImporter\Graphics\YahooLogo.jpg` to the url location of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Graphics is the folder in your project directory then give relative path to `@Url.Content()` and it will handle it itself.

give url this way:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Graphics/YahooLogo.jpg")"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use absolute image file path. Put it inside web root folder and use relative path instead.

UPD: have a look here for examples http://www.dotnetperls.com/mappath

Answer (score 1):

If you reference a file then you should add 'file://' to your image url.

Give it a try